# how to encrypt and decrypt pashto language in iphone using sqlite

Tags: iphone

I am creating one dictionary project and client want security because he is having very rare       data so he want to encrypt and decrypt the data from sqlite.

i m able to encrypt english   letter but i am unable to decrypt pashto language.

will you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Have tested: [SQCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) ?
Its an easy full sqlite encryption for iOS